How to execute redis-cli commands on container start-up from docker-compose
So I want to create an index in Redis server which is started as a docker container, but without manually doing docker exec -it container_name redis-cli. Basically, I started with a sh script to do that desired redis-cli command but getting an error in doing so.
Here is my best-effort-attempt with compose:
version: "3.9"
services:

  redis-db:
    container_name: container_name 
    image: "redis/redis-stack"
    command: /usr/local/etc/redis/index-create.sh
    volumes:
      - ./redis_folder/index-create.sh:/usr/local/etc/redis/index-create.sh
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

Inside my local directory under /redis_folder/index-create.sh:
sleep 5
redis-cli FT.CREATE myIndex ON HASH PREFIX 1 studentPrefixProject SCHEMA "studentName" TAG" "SEPARATOR" "|"
EOF

The image has to be redis/redis-stack

Most likely you don't have the redis-cli installed, if you are on ubuntu, you can get it by installing the redis package, the redis-tools package, or by installing redis-insight: https://redis.io/insight/ and accessing the cli from there.

I can do docker exec -it container_name redis-cli and i'm in redis-cli, therefore, it is already there..

You haven't said what error you get, which may help us help you. Also, you confirmed you could run the redis-cli within the container but have you confirmed the sh file is in there? And did running THAT from inside the container work (as a sanity check?) Also, there may be better ways to achieve your goal. For instance, would it make sense to create the db as a volume and reuse that rather than creating it from WITHIN the container?
